# gvim ftplugin not loaded

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

### I'm trying to figure this out:

- Added `~/.vim/ftplugin/verilog.vim` with my commands (matchit rules)
- Started gvim and opened a verilog file.
  Now:

  - `:set filetype?` returns `filetype=verilog`
  - `:filetype` returns `filetype detection=ON plugin=ON indent=OFF`

At this point it looks like verilog.vim **wasn't loaded** (matchit doesn't match).
Only when running `:source ~/.vim/ftplugin/verilog.vim` - my commands are loaded (and matchit match correctly)

### Any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Mystery solved.

When running `:scriptnames` I can see that that my verilog.vim was loaded, but another verilog.vim was loaded afterwards and overrode my settings.
After moving `~/.vim/ftplugin/verilog.vim` to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/verilog.vim` it works!

Comment: As a fellow Verilog programmer, let me share with you my improved version of the verilog_systemverilog syntax addon https://github.com/vhda/verilog_systemverilog.vim

Answer (score 2):

Assuming *nix:  Vim directory should be `~/.vim` not `~/vim`.

Comment: And on Windows, it would be ~/vimfiles rather than ~/vim. In fact from :help vimfiles, it looks like ~/vim is not a default location on *any* system.

Comment: It was a typo, the directory is ".vim" and the problem is there.

Comment: I fixed the typo in the question